# Area51's related proposals list returned poor results

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

When I created the [French Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29528/french-language-usage?referrer=WvGJEN4Dvw5YLAxnZ_eZ1A2) proposal a few minutes ago, which is a proposal I know to have [at least two similar proposals](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/on-the-multiple-french-sites), the suggestions to avoid having duplicate didn't mention French until very much further down the line.

Here's the list I got:

> Latin Language and Usage:
>   Russian language and usage:
>   English Language & Usage:
>   Spanish Language and Usage:
>   Italian Language and Usage: 
>   Portuguese Language:
>   Chinese Language:
>   Hindi Language:
>   Speech-Language Pathology:
>   Planned Languages:
>   Language Preservation:
>   SAS Programming Language:
>   Dutch Language and Usage:
>   **English/French Translation:**
>   Natural Language Processing and Computational Linguistics (NLP/CL):
>   Programming Language [closed]:
>   German language:
>   French Stack Overflow:
>   **French language:**
>   **Le bon usage du français [French usage]:**

I could understand all the "Language & Usage" and "Language and Usage" sites being at the top, but why are the ones containing French so far at the bottom? Both "French usage" and "French language" share two words with my proposal. Many of the proposals above them only share one word in common (language).

If the results are always this poor, it's unsurprising that we get so many duplicated on Area51.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that the list purports to be sorted most-likely to least-likely match. But as a list of suggested duplicates, it looks pretty good.

I would point out that you saw the list, spotted *two* duplicates, and created another proposal anyway. I'm sure you had your reasons, but the list seems to have worked as far as it could have.

Comment: I had to scroll all the way down. Only the top four results were visible without scrolling down. I would **not** have scrolled down this far if I didn't know there were two similar proposals. My behavior was not normal; under normal circumstances, I would have assumed that there were no similar proposals. The only reason I scrolled down that far was to get information to write this bug report.

Comment: Perhaps the devs can fix (or add) a better sort order. I was not aware there *was* a sort order, or if there even *is* one.

Comment: Should I rewrite the question as a feature request asking for sort order, or is that unnecessary?

Comment: @Borror0: Probably unnecessary unless you get a [status-bydesign]